# Onclick action doesnt go to the method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

here is the code from my cshtml file

```
<button type="button" class="button js-book-class" onclick="@Url.Action("BookTheClass", "MemberArea", new { ClassID = Aclass.ClassID })">Book Now</button>
```

and here my function inside MemberAreaController.cs

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ContentResult BookTheClass(int ClassID)
        {
            Class selectedClass= _context.classes.Find(ClassID);
            selectedClass.spaceUsed++;
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Content(ClassID.ToString());//just for testing
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have conflict.

`Url.Action` generates a href link, which in click, will execute a browser navigation, which means **GET** request.

While your server `BookTheClass` action is expected to be called when executing a `POST`.

The easy fix which in this case is also the not so good solution, is to change your method to `[HttpGet]` (which i believe is the default) and it will be resolved.

The more accurate solution, will be to create a form element and making the button submit the data, this will acquire you a change only in HTML and not server side.

The reason i think you should stick to `Post`, is because i believe in the notion that **GET** should be consider as a query like, and that identical requests should have the same response.
Whereas **Post** should have the role of Actions which result in side-effects. which in **Rest**, means Creation. But as general rule of changing a state in the server as a result.

Comment: What do you propose is the best way to run a method from a control on view button click without restarting the page?

Comment: I would usually use Ajax to perform this, look for a simple tutorial on ajax preferably with Asp.Net to perform request and handle the response as you see fit.

Comment: You can just use javascript to post the data to the url you want and then do something with the response